# What is the Xpath of YouTube Description box?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to use selenium and edit my posted videos but I cannot find the XPath of Description box of YouTube. Can anyone tell me what is the Xpath of the description box?
I tried this

```
//*[@id="description"]
```

but it does not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below xpath for the URL https://studio.youtube.com/

```
//div[@aria-label="Tell viewers about your video"]
```